# Set activemq priority using ProducerTemplate

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

Is it possible to do this?

I am trying to send to the queue using this:

```
producerTemplate.sendBodyAndProperty("activemq:queue.queue", message, "JMSPriority", priority);
```

I have setup the JMSConfiguration thus:

```
JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration(pooledConnectionFactory);
jmsConfiguration.setDeliveryPersistent(false); // do not store a copy of the messages on the queue
jmsConfiguration.setPreserveMessageQos(true);
jmsConfiguration.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
```

and I have also enabled queueing in `activemq.xml`:

```
<policyEntry queue=">" prioritizedMessages="true" useCache="false" expireMessagesPeriod="0" queuePrefetch="1" >
</policyEntry>
```

Yet, when I send the message using the producertemplate, the priority as it shows up in activemq is 0:

[image]

Even though when I send the message normally (`producerTemplate.sendBodyAndProperty("activemq:queue.queue", message)`) the priority shows up as 4.

Comment: I think JMSPriority should be a header rather than a property

Comment: Brilliant! No wonder it wasn't working!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JMSPriority` should be a header rather than a property.

```
producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader("activemq:queue.queue", message, "JMSPriority", priority);
```